# How to combine "lines3d" and "scatterplot3d" in R?

Tags: r, math, graph, plot, scatter-plot

I have this task where I have to plot a 3d surface graph. I have few variables i.e.:

```
K = 1:11
F = 1:11
M = 1:11
S4P = 1:100
GNOP = 1:1000
```

I want to plot a 3d surface plot. For which I did

```
library(scatterplot3d)
scatterplot3d(K,F,M)
```

and then I have to add lines to it so I did

```
library(rgl)
lines3d(S4P,GNOP,M)
```

But lines are not drawn on the plot but shown as a separate graph without any axis. How can I combine both?

Comment: Aren't these two functions from entirely different packages with entirely different methods of plotting? They are not really compatible in that case.

Comment: The `lines3d`-function is from pkg:rgl. Despite the similarity of the names, `scatterplot3d` has nothing to do with the functions from the rgl-package. There is a `scatter3d` in the car-pkg that does depend on rgl so perhaps you should use that function instead.  `scatterplot3d` is a base graphics package and function.

Comment: @BondedDust - `scatterplot3d` doesn't turn up in any of my base packages - though it may use base plotting functions as opposed to rgl.

Comment: If you were really keen, you could also do this using `persp` `points` `lines` and `trans3d`

Comment: @thelatemail: You may be confused because `scatterplot3d`, the function, is in 'scatterplot3d', the package, written by Martin Maechler. And if you look at the code, you see it is all base graphics. The rgl package (by Duncan Murdoch) has the function `lines3d`.